# Gnome Window context menu has no mnemonics?

Tags: gnome

[This web tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/how-to-use-keyboard-shortcut-to-toggle.html) says press `Alt+Space` then `t` to select "Always on Top", but on my computer (Wayland Gnome 43.2) pressing `t` does nothing. Also, pressing `e` when the window menu is showing does not show any underlines for mnemonics. Does the current version of Gnome support mnemonics? If so, how can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be no longer supported: [How to use window menu accelerators/mnemonics in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032810/1086345)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon This is a joke... I often invoke the window context menu using the keyboard shortcut Alt+Space, even under Windows, when a window's title bar is invisible. Windows, of course, have mnemonics for that menu, and it seems that all other Linux DE's do, too. Why did Gnome remove the mnemonics? I cannot think of any good reason for that... Is this really a bug?

Comment: I know, this is very annoying :/. Gnome is good but lacks features or they are removed.  I don't think is a bug but developers might think is not necessary certain feature and then is removed. Indeed, some features are *recovered* 
by using  gnome shell extensions but it seems the mnemonics are not possible by using some extension.